# Parents' Canada tourist visa

Tags: canada, tourist-visas

My country of origin is India. I want my parents to pay me a visit in Canada. I am a permanent resident here.

**Problem:**

My father is a self-employed businessman and so I'm not sure about the documents about his business. From what I have googled they say you should give reasons why you want to go back.

His annual income as per ITR is 550,000 rupees.

He doesn't have a business registration as it's a small business. But he has a website, trademark information, enough bank balance, a current account etc.

My mother is also self-employed but she has a boutique and again she doesn't have any business registration or any solid proof. Her annual income as per ITR is 500,000 rupees.

Worst part: My parents already have 2 USA rejections in their history of tourist visas.

So, can anyone suggest something? I don't want them to face another rejection because I want them to come here.

Comment: Have you considered the [super visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/parent-grandparent-super-visa.html)?

Comment: What were the reasons for the US visa rejections?

Comment: @phoog although I know about it but I didn't think about it. Can you elaborate the pros of going for super visa instead of visitor visa in terms of high probability of getting the visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth they never mentioned the reasons. It was always like insufficient documents. But didn't get into much details of it.

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni Unfortunately, I have no idea whether there is a different probability of getting the visa.  All I know for sure is that the maximum length of each visit is greater with the super visa.  For a super visa application, they surely understand that in many cases the costs will be borne by the family in Canada rather than by the visitors themselves.  But they probably understand the same for regular visa applications as well.

Comment: If they have their own businesses in India and intend to return to them after having only a short visit in Canada, then the super visa is probably not a good idea.